# Customer Attrition in SQL Server

Tags: sql-server

I am trying to find churned customer in the `adventureworks2012` sample database. Churned customer in my case is a customer who used to be active in a period of six months, then has not made any transaction in a later period of time.

My attributes are customer ID, product category, product subcategories, price, order dates, online order flag etc

Can you please provide some hints on how to define teacher customer as either churned or not churned.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Is order dates the attribute you want to use to determine "last transaction"?  And how are they stored relative to your customer table.

Comment: Hello Mason, that is right I am using order dates to determine last transaction. Do you mean date format? If yes it in the form of year-month-day. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

If you're trying to loop through them all:

```
SELECT TEACHER_ID, MAX(ORDER_DATE) FROM ORDERS GROUP BY TEACHER_ID
```

Will give you each teachers last order date, and then you can loop through and compare them to whatever date range you want (if you're doing a loop).

If you're trying to figure out an individual teacher just see if the count is > 0:

```
SELECT COUNT(*) AS COUNT FROM ORDERS WHERE TEACHER_ID = ? AND ORDER_DATE > (NOW() - INTERVAL 6 MONTH)
```

Best I can do w\o a better idea what language you're using and what the application is.